# Angularjs + restangular, search albums & artists on spotify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, spotify, restangular

I use restangular module to make connections to the spotify API and get search results of Albums and artists.

When i fetch an album or an artist , it is ok. The problem is when i pass **params** to restangular in order to search for results. **restangular converts the symols `&` and `=` to special characters , and that makes the URL not working**

For example i have the below snippet to search for albums/artists:

```
//I pass : https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=album:lo%20artist:lo&type=album,artist

const params = "album:lo+artist:lo&type=album,artist";
Restangular.all(SEARCH_END_POINT).getList({q: params}).then(function(data){
      console.log("All ok");
      console.log(data[0].name);
    }, function(response) {
      console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
    });
```

**But i get this FALSE URL:** 
[image]

Can somebody tell me how **these symbols remain the same** `&` and `=` ?

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things wrong here.

1. **URL search**: you have two queries shown as one. ("q" and "type")
2. **Result type**: You said getList, the search API doesn't return an Array, it returns an object.

   Restangular.one('search')
       .get({ q: params, type: 'album,artist' })
       .then(function (res) {
           console.log(res);
       });